# youtube suggestions algorithm

Tags: video, relations

I am very curious to know how youtube generates its suggestions for a particular video. I am from India and I listen to Indian songs on youtube. It sometimes gives suggestions that are totally unconnected but its the next song I want to listen because they are from the same or similar genre. Is there some machine learning based genre classifying technique used? Or is it just number of common views between the videos?

Answer (score 2):

It's based on the text and header that is written for the video (e.g., if a video is titled "Metallica in Rome 1995", others videos with "Metallica in Rome" in header will follow, further down will "Metallica" come, and even further down "Rome".

Youtube can analyze videos (used foremost as a way of stopping illegal uploading of videos, such as TV series and such) so if the video is something their database knows anything about, suggestions can be based on that.

What viewers view next is also in the suggestions box so it's a mix between those.

Answer (score 0):

Very good feature for suggestions is to show content that was favourited and rated by those who also like the content you see at the moment. Probably YOUtube can also use it, but I'm not 100% sure.